Coding the wait function from Teraterm in Python
I am working on a project where I want to port some Teraterm scripts into Python. I got something working but it is not really matching what I want: read each lines on the UART until either a timeout occurs or a string, within a defined list, is identified.
To be more precise, I would like to port something like the following into python:

sendln 'ATI9'

wait "OK" "+CME ERROR" (or timeout)


(Note that the response from the modem contains several lines that end with an "OK")
In python I have implemented the following 2 options but I am not really happy with the result:
using either a time.sleep or ser.timeout and read_until from pyserial :

Send AT Command
def send_at_command(ser, command, timeout):
    print(f'Sending: {command}')
    ser.write((command + '\r\n').encode('utf-8'))
    time.sleep(timeout)  # Wait for the response
    response = ser.read_all().decode('utf-8')
    print(f'Response: {response}')
    return response


same as before with timeout managed by pyserial instead of a sleep
def send_at_command2(ser, command, timeout):
    try:
        print(f'Sending: {command}')
        ser.timeout = timeout  # Wait for the response
        ser.write((command + '\r\n').encode('utf-8'))
        ser.reset_output_buffer()
        response = ser.read_until('\r').decode('utf-8')
        print(f'Response: {response}')
        #ser.reset_input_buffer()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'No response to {command} : {str(e)}') 
        print(f'Response {response} : {ser.read_all()}') 
        ser.close()
        otii.shutdown()
        connection.close_connection()
        server.terminate()
        sys.exit()
    return response


Validate Response
def validate_response(response, expected_keywords):
    if any(keyword in response for keyword in expected_keywords):
        #print('Test passed.')
        return True
    else:
        #print('Test failed.')
        return False


Test AT command Response
def Wait_At_Command_Response(ser, command, timeout, expected_keywords):
    response = send_at_command2(ser,command, timeout)
    #response = send_at_command(ser,command, timeout)
    return validate_response(response, expected_keywords)

Then I call the following in my main function:
Wait_At_Command_Response(ser,'ATI9',2,['+CME ERROR', 'OK'])
Those 2 options seem to take a very long time to process the response from the AT command. Moreover I often get messages such as "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xXX in position 0: invalid start byte"
Thanks
See description for details
